# Entity reference : show fields instead of Label

Tags: entities

Each user has a personal calendar (tab in profile from Views) where they can add "Event" content-type. I have a Entity reference field where the user can add 5 different "friends" to this "Event".

With Entity Reference view Widget I have a view (Picture and user name) from which the user can add up to 5 people. And it works, but...

How can I have more than just the Label? I would like to have the user picture and his name.

I've tried for 2 days... Please help. Maybe Entity Referennce is not the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to check the display settings (IE: Manage Display) of both the referencing and referenced entity.  Haven't used it in a while, but definitely worth a look.